# Is there a way to stop QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an ellipse that moves from certain position upwards.

```
void Equalizer::advance(int phase)
{
    if(!phase) return;

    QPointF location = this->pos();
    setPos(mapToParent(0 , -(speed)));
 }
```

Though I want it to  stop moving when it reaches certain y coordinate. How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use a QPropertyAnimation instead?  It is much better at handling almost anything you can think of like this.

Comment: @phyatt, `better` is subjective. If handling realtime movement of a player object in a game, based on user input, it's not something I'd want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update its y position, when it reaches the specified y coordinate,

```
void Equalizer::advance(int phase)
{
    if(!phase) return;

    QPointF location = this->pos();

    if(location.y() <= specifiedY)
    {
        //If the speed at which the ellipse is moving is great enough to take it beyond the specifiedY, set it to the specifiedY before the return.
        setPos(pos().x(), specifiedY); // assuming specifiedY is in scene coordinates
        return;
    }        
    setPos(mapToParent(0 , -(speed)));
 }
```

Comment: But wouldn't it cause the infinite loop where QGraphicsScene keeps calling that without effect?

Comment: @JackNickolson, try it and see what happens ;O)